# R Shiny, shinyapps.io printing error messages for R codes

Tags: r, shiny, eval

I was trying to create a Shiny app that takes code blocks and runs the code then gives the output for that code block.

To do that I take a textInput, then with the following, tried to provide outputs for users.

```
Question1 <- reactive({
    eval(parse(text=input$Question1_code))
})

output$Question1_output <- renderText({
    input$Run_Code
    isolate(paste(Question1()))
})
```

Now, my problem is when I run this on locally, the output I get for wrong statements/codes e.g.

```
seq(1,10,-2)
```

is **wrong sign in 'by' argument**. (which is what I would like to see for a wrong statement)

However, when I run it on shinyapps.io, I get the following error message,

**An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.**

How can I print the same error message that I am getting locally (wrong sign in 'by' argument) on shinyapps.io too?

Comment: What do you mean `print the same error message on shinyapps.io`? Do you want to see it on UI?

Comment: @Iz100 Yes actually. I want to print the error/warning messages on UI. The error messages can be shown when I run the app locally, but I cannot print the messages on my web app.

Comment: @OrcunOltulu Reagrding `eval(parse(...`, make sure you read the chapter on security in [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/index.html), especially: https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-security.html#compute-resources

Comment: @markus thanks for the feedback, I will look at that document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`shinyCatch`](https://systempipe.org/sps/funcs/spscomps/reference/shinyCatch.html) from [spsComps](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps)

Example for your case:

```r
library(shiny)
library(spsComps)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("a", "blocking"),
  actionButton("b", "no blocking"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$a, {
      spsComps::shinyCatch({
          seq(1,10,-2)
      },
      # blocking recommended
      blocking_level = "error",
      prefix = "My-project" #change console prefix if you don't want "SPS"
      )
      # some other following actions will NOT  be run 
      print("other actions")
    })
    
    # if you dont want to block
    observeEvent(input$b, {
        spsComps::shinyCatch({
            seq(1,10,-2)
        }, prefix = "My-project")
        # some other following actions will run 
        print("other actions")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

or try more demos [here](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps#demos)

Comment: @Iz100 thank you for that sample code. shinyCatch() seems to solve my problem

Comment: @OrcunOltulu great, then you could consider accepting this post as the best answer.