# Shiny: Display console output during specific function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny app that, upon clicking an `observeEvent` button, calls a function that outputs useful information to the console.  I'd like to be able to show the console contents to the user, but only when this particular function is running.  So in pseudocode, in my `server` it would show:

```
start_displaying_console()

myoutput <- complex_function_that_takes_awhile_with_important_console_info(arg1="hello",arg2="goodbye")

end_displaying_console()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where in the app do you want to display the contents of the console?

Comment: I have a `shinydashboard` with multiple tabs.  Essentially, clicking an `observeEvent` button on one of the tabs kicks off the `complex_function`, I want the console output to show up right below the `observeEvent` button.

Comment: Does the complex function involves an iteration/for-loop that calls print() on each or some iteration? Or you want just to print a message when the functions finishes executing?

Comment: I do not know the specific mechanics of it.  It's an optimization solver function that prints the progress of the solve, to the console, including important details besides "all done." I already have an indicator that the function is finished executing; I want to see the console output in the shiny app.

Comment: Is the function available in a package? My guess is to edit the source code of that function to instead of printing to the console use the approach provided by @lz100 and call `message`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shinyCatch`](https://systempipe.org/sps/funcs/spscomps/reference/shinyCatch.html) from [spsComps](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps)

Example for your case:

```r
library(shiny)
library(spsComps)
ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("a", "console messages"),
    actionButton("b", "console warnings"),
    actionButton("c", "console errors")
)

my_long_func1 <- function(){
    message("some msg")
}
my_long_func2 <- function(){
    warning("some warnings")
}
my_long_func3 <- function(){
    stop("some errors")
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$a, {
        spsComps::shinyCatch({
            my_long_func1()
        },
        # blocking recommended
        blocking_level = "error",
        prefix = "My-project" #change console prefix if you don't want "SPS"
        )
    })
    observeEvent(input$b, {
        spsComps::shinyCatch({
            my_long_func2()
        },
        # blocking recommended
        blocking_level = "error",
        prefix = "My-project" 
        )
    })
    observeEvent(input$c, {
        spsComps::shinyCatch({
            my_long_func3()
        },
        # blocking recommended
        blocking_level = "error",
        prefix = "My-project"
        )
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

read docs and try more demos [here](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps#demos)

also in my another answer: [R Shiny, shinyapps.io printing error messages for R codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70354765/r-shiny-shinyapps-io-printing-error-messages-for-r-codes/70356019#70356019)